# Is it possible to playback a playready content protedted mpeg-dash streaming by HTML5/Pure javascript player on Android4.4(Chrome)?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, mpeg-dash, playready

I think that the implementations of Encripted Media Extension(EME) and Content Decryption Module(CDM) are required to playback the content protected mpeg-dash streaming by a HTML5/pure javascript player.

Are EME and CDM implemented on Android 4.4 with Chrome for playback a mpeg-dash streaming which is encrypted by Microsoft playready?

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome on Android 4.4., you can only use Widevine-protected MPEG-DASH/MPEG-CENC content within the HTML5 EME. You can try out this DRM demo at http://www.dash-player.com/drm_demopage/, which works with Widevine Modular on Chrome on Android.

Each browser platform has to provides different CDMs, e.g. on Chrome you have Widevine Modular, on IE11 on Windows 8 you have PlayReady, this article gives an overview on that: http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2015/02/the-status-of-mpeg-dash-today-and-why-youtube-and-netflix-use-it-in-html5/.